# Log processing tool

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, elk

I have a new requirement.  I need a tool, which will 
1.push logs / KPIs from customer end to a backend server, 
2.That server must process those logs, and trigger events on any unusual events.ex: exception/ crash , null pointer exceptions, usage of new feature, wrong business inputs.
3.should provide summary of metrics.
I tried to understand logstash, some how I didn't get it clearly .
Any suggestions of such tool please?
 Thx,
--Gopi

Comment: Do more research on ELBK. Format your requirements properly. Also, look at this https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-alerting

Comment: @Krishna Thanks. I edited my comments. I am going thru elastic.co, but will it provide "trigger events on any unusual events.ex: exception/ crash , null pointer exceptions, usage of new feature, wrong business inputs" ?

Comment: @Gopi yes, it provides such features.